# VS 2010 Layer Diagram Validation Error is Showing A Dependency That Doesn't Even Exist (AV0001)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, architecture

I'm getting the following validation error on my layer diagram:

```
Error   65  AV0001 : Invalid Dependency : Weld.Interface.Core(Assembly) --> Weld.Interface(Namespace)
    Layers: Application Framework Core, Application Framework   |   Dependencies: Namespace Reference   D:\Projects\Windows Projects\Weld\Weld\ModelingProject1\Weld.layerdiagram   0   0   ModelingProject1
```

These 2 assemblies are set up as different layers and the assembly name represents the namespace starting point as well.

> Weld.Interface.Core: This assembly and namespace does not have a reference to Weld.Interface and only references .NET Framework classes
>
> Weld.Interface: This assembly and namespace does not have a reference to Weld.Interface.Core

There is no dependency between these two layers in the dependency diagram.  I am confused why I am getting this error.  No dependency in the project or code, and no dependency is even setup in the layer diagram.

Somehow the Validation logic in the layer diagram is seeing a non existent dependency and saying it is an error.

Any ideas what either I might have missed or what is causing this problem?

Comment: I'm essentially getting the exact same thing in my project.  It's complaining of a invalid dependency between a method on an interface and a static extension method.  There are absolutely no references made to each other from the respective method declarations and, honestly, they're about as disparate functionality-wise as can possibly be.

Did you ever get any resolution to this issue on your project?

Comment: Follow up question -- are you utilizing generics at all in the code it's complaining about?  The error message I receive complains how there are dependencies of "References Generic Parameter, References Generic" and, indeed, both methods in question are generic methods.

Comment: Updated info -- please see my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out what was going on with my situation and thought I'd pass it along here.  It appears to be an issue of cached references to assemblies.  When the modeling project was originally created, it was in its own solution, separate from the assemblies it's intending to model.  As such, it required listing them within the Layer References for the Modeling project.

The project has since been incorporated into the overall solution, but I believe the project references originally declared when separate from the solution kept precedence and, ultimately, was referencing old code.  I removed the assemblies from the Layer References of the Modeling project and everything was smooth sailing after that.