# VS 2010 - Architecture Validation - Ignore Errors by Type?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, modeling

Thanks to a set of extension methods in a common assembly, we see errors like this fairly often:

> Error 1   AV0001 : Invalid Dependency : App.Common.SpecialList<>.ConvertTo<>(Method) --> App.DataLayer.Identifier(Type)
>       Layers: Common, Data Layer   |   Dependencies: References Generic Parameter C:\Validation.layerdiagram  0   0   App.Modeling

It seems this is a common enough problem (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951533/vs-2010-layer-diagram-validation-error-is-showing-a-dependency-that-doesnt-even)).

It is easy enough to suppress them one at a time, but fairly annoying.  Is there any way to suppress this "Dependencies: References Generic Parameter" error globally?  Or even better, to suppress it for calls going into a single layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this directly in the box.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In the end, we couldn't get the architecture validation step running as part of our CI process anyway (TeamCity) so I think we're going to need to beg for some money for NDepend licenses.